# How to add compile c++ flags for NDK builder

Tags: c++, android-ndk, pthreads, eclipse-cdt

I am compiling a multi threaded library (`dlib`) using eclipse. This library is included in the `jni` folder. How can include the `-pthread` or `-pthreads` options while building the `NDK` project with the `dlib` library?

Comment: This is controlled by **jni/Android.mk** file (and optionally **jni/Application.mk** file). You can read more about these files at **[android.mk](http://android.mk/)**.